# Как изменить текущее время в Mysql?

Tags: mysql

База данных Mysql не верно показывает время, получаю командой `SELECT NOW();`

Пробовал менять часовой пояс командой `SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+5:00';` но время не меняется

Answer (score 1):

[NOW() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)

> NOW([fsp])
> --
> Returns the current date and time as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' or YYYYMMDDhhmmss format, depending on whether the function is used in string or numeric context. **The value is expressed in the session time zone.**

Значение, возвращаемое `NOW()`, приводится к зоне времени, установленной в настройках сессии (соединения) - так что менять глобальную зону совершенно бессмысленно. Настраивайте именно соединение.

Или просто перед запросом времени установите нужную зону запросом

```
SET @@time_zone = '+5:00';
```

Но помните - закрытие и последующее открытие соединения (в т.ч. при ошибке и переподключении) потребует заново установить зону соединения.